Certbot `http-01` challenge fails with unauthorized error for domain verification
I’m trying to obtain an SSL certificate for my domain registry.cuongncc.uk using Certbot with the --standalone authenticator.
The http-01 challenge fails with details:
certbot certonly --standalone -d registry.cuongncc.uk --preferred-challenges http --agree-tos -m myemail@gmail.com --keep-until-expiring -v

Output
Requesting a certificate for registry.cuongncc.uk
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for registry.cuongncc.uk
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain registry.cuongncc.uk
http-01 challenge for registry.cuongncc.uk

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: registry.cuongncc.uk
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 2606:4700:3037::6815:57b4: Invalid response from http://registry.cuongncc.uk/.well-known/acme-challenge/RuR-1jApRXG5MPzRCHacjG-x-PyyS2hMGnboqXdn8qs: 522

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

I have checked:

DNS Configuration: Confirmed that the domain registry.cuongncc.uk points to the correct IPv6 address of my server.
Firewall Settings: Ensured that port 80 is open and accessible from the Internet.
Temporary Standalone Server: Confirmed that no other service is running on port 80 during the execution of Certbot.

My Environment:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 on AWS
Certbot Version: 2.9.0

How to fix this problem?
I expect Certbot to successfully complete the http-01 challenge by serving the challenge file from the temporary standalone webserver, verifying domain ownership, and issuing the SSL certificate.

2606:4700:3037::6815:57b4 is CloudFlare. Do CF do some magic handling of .well_known that you're unaware of? Check the logs in CF.
